# Proof based on orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

I'm hoping to show that $|Q| = +1$ or $-1$ if $Q$ is a $p \times p$ orthogonal matrix.

Since I know that $|QQ'| = |I|$ and $|Q||Q'| = |Q|^2$, then $|Q|^2 = |I|$

How should I approach this proof(alternative proof) with the definition of the determinant of the square matrix $k \times k$, such that

$$|A| = a_{11} \quad \text{if }\,k=1$$
$$|A| = \sum_{j=0}^k a_{1j} |A_{1j}| (-1)^{1+j}  \quad \text{if }\, k>1$$

where $A_{1j}$ is the $(k-1) \times (k-1)$ matrix obtained by deleting the first row $j$th column of $A$.

Correct me if I'm wrong. If $Q$ = |I|, then $Q = [q_{ij}], Q_{ij} = 0, i\ne j$

$$|Q| = q_{11}Q_{11}+0+...+0 = 1 ?$$

Comment: it should be $|Q|^2 = 1$, not $|Q|^2 = I$. The result follows immediately from this, so are you asking for an alternative proof?

Comment: @CalvinKhor It was a typo, I just made the edit.

Comment: And what of my question?

Comment: @CalvinKhor It is $|Q|^2 = |I|$ not $|Q|^2 = 1$

Comment: Do you know that $|I|=1$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, but the question asked to use the definition of determinant. I believe that will be an alternative proof in this case.

Comment: Since you can only use the definition of the determinant none of your initial notes about things like $|Q|^2 = 1$ can be used. you should, however, see something happen in the sum when multiplying $Q$ by it's transpose.

Comment: @DaveNine Hi, I believe we are not limited to only use the definition of determinant.